# cocos2d - is it faster to draw a primitive shape (e.g. ccDrawCircle, drawDot) or draw a sprite?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, rendering

I have to draw a number sprites and also a very large circle, and I'm wondering if is it better to draw that circle using `ccDrawCircle`, or to make a circle sprite and draw it as a regular sprite?  In terms of memory, I'd be using up a lot to store basically nothing but a giant circle; but is it faster to do all the drawing as one batch?  What if I had to split it up into two batches, one for the circle and another for the other sprites?  Is it faster to draw a primitive shape or to draw a sprite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ccDraw* methods aren't batch-drawn and meant for debugging, they are not particularly efficient.

CCDrawNode is a much better option as it can batch-draw primitives, but it doesn't allow primitives to be removed without recreating them all.

Batched sprites are usually the best option. How much this affects fps depends on your use case and targeted devices. Problem is they don't "scale" well, so it's best to have each required size of a shape as a separate image. On the other hand you can tint (colorize) a grayscale image in order to have more color variety without having to have each shape with different colors as separate images.

Comment: I think CCDrawNode is probably the best option for me- would I just add the shapes to the same batch node as my other sprites, or would I need a new batch node just for primitives?

Comment: no batch node, they are for sprites. ccdrawnode is its own batchnode